# Permutation's decomposition into transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

1. Transposition is a cycle with 2 elements.
2. Any permutation can be decomposed into a product of transpositions.

For example, for permutation

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ 
2 & 3 & 1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$

decomposition is

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

but why are $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$ transpositions? Aren't they not even cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cycle of length 2 is called a transposition, of course it switches (transposes) two elements.

$$
(1 3) =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 4
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Comment: i can't understand the logic here, for (1 2) 1->2, 2->3, where is cycle?

Comment: $(1 2)$ means $1 \to 2$ and $2 \to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

They're cycles of length $2$, and `odd` permutations.

The parity of a permutation can be defined as the parity of the number of transpositions in its decomposition as a product of transpositions (this parity does not depend on the particular decomposition. As such, a transposition is odd. More generally a cycle of length $n$ has signature equal to $(-1)^{n-1}$.